# Contain Text within Picture area using Position: relative;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I'm trying to figure out how to use Position: relative in order to keep an object (let's call it text) in the same place on the screen regardless of screen size.

When I use Position: relative, and set "left" to 30% for example... It's 30% of the screen. I'm trying to figure out how to put text on top of an image and set the text to be 30% left within the image. I need this to work regardless of the screen size. So far I have been unable.

Could someone explain to me how Position Relative and Position Absolute work in these kinds of situations? Or how this would best be handled?

Thanks!

Here's my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3h1ogms/1/), and here's the snippet

```css
.center {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
body {
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /* for IE 6 */
}
.element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-family: 'Just Me Again Down Here', cursive;
}
.input {
  /*color: blue;*/
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 220px;
  left: 18%;
  width: 480px;
  height: 475px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Just Me Again Down Here', cursive;
}
```

```html
<img id='image' class='center' src='https://s13.postimg.org/li2l28a0n/White_Board.gif'>


<h1 class='element'>This is a header </h1>
<textarea id='text1' class='input' placeholder="Write your answer here."></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First we setup a div with a `.desk` class, desk will receive the desired background image, a fixed width and height, and it will `margin 0 auto` since the desk doesn't have a container.
2. The `.header` class doesn't need to be absolute, we use it within the desk which is already positioned relatively. We give it a little padding so it will fit in the desk image.
3. The `.answer` class is applied to the `textarea` element we give it a `width 100%;` since we use it within the `.desk` which already has pre-defined width, that means `.answer` will equip all of possible width within the desk.

A great tip is always think simple in CSS, understand the usage of `position: absolute`, when it's really necessary. By the way if you're unfamiliar with `rem` sizing, I suggest you take a look here: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/

Good luck!

You can get the desired effect in a much simpler code.. have a look:

```
body {
  background-color: #27ae60;
}

.desk {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(https://s13.postimg.org/li2l28a0n/White_Board.gif);
  width:560px;
  height:839px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header { 
   padding: .5rem 0 0 2rem;
   font-size: 2.5rem;
   font-family: 'Just Me Again Down Here', cursive;
}

.answer { 
   width: 100%;
   margin-left: 2rem;
   outline: none;
   border: none;
   background-color: transparent;
   overflow: hidden;
   resize: none;
   font-size: 2rem;
   font-family: 'Just Me Again Down Here', cursive;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y3h1ogms/5/

Comment: This is great. Can you edit your answer a little to explain why this works better?

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi I tried to explain the best, see my edit :)

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 1):

When set `position: relative` on an element, it will be positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor, where "positioned" according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) means:

> A positioned element is an element whose computed position property is either relative, absolute, fixed or sticky.

In your example, the header is not a descendant of the image, so there's no way to position it relative to the image. What you might do instead is convert the `<img>` to a `<div>` set the `background-image` of your div to be the image URL. You would also need to explicitly set the width and height of the div.